# Print text file if it exists, or print it does not exist

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the full text of a text file. But if that text file does not exist, I want it to print that it does not exist, otherwise it wont let the rest of the code work.

Printing out only the text files works

```
for x in ABC:
    print(f"{x}:")
    with open("./" + x + "/Log.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

However, when I am trying to see if that file is found, I get an error. This is how I tried to do it (it is wrong)

```
for x in ABC:
    print(f"{x}:")
    with open("./" + x + "/Log.txt") as f:
        if f.empty:
            print("No files found.")
        else:
            print(f.read())
```

Comment: Strangely I couldn't see any ticks on any answer of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is this:

```
for x in ABC:
    print(f"{x}:")
    try:
        with open(f"./{x}/Log.txt") as f:
            print(f.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
```

Checking beforehand leaves your code open to race conditions, where a file is deleted *after* you check it's existence but *before* you try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the file exists, and if it does print the contents; otherwise say it doesn't exist:

```
import os

filename = 'foo.txt'

if os.path.isfile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
else:
    print(filename + ' does not exist.')
```